# Infinity DateTime to SqlDateTime

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, datetime

I used SQL Statements in the SQL Server Management Studio, where I entered as infinity validity the following datetime {ts '9999-12-31 23:59:59'}, but when I try to do this via SqlConnection & SqlCommand, the Server Response, that this datetime conversion is out of range ... Is there any way to get this without error?

thank you so much in advance

Comment: Why don't you use `NULL` in case of "infinity"?

Comment: actually this wasn't my idea, it was developed long time ago and would not match in all the other processes -.-

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you should use `SqlDateTime.MaxValue` in order to do so.

Source: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqltypes.sqldatetime.maxvalue(v=vs.110).aspx

Another way to do it would be to declare this variable in the SQL as optional and assigning the datetime there. THis way you don't need to worry about framework changes or anything.

```
ALTER PROCEDURE  [dbo].[YourProcedure]
@Date datetime = '9999-12-31 23:59:59';
```

This way anytime you DON'T actually pass the value it will be as you desire without problems.

Comment: Thank you very much, this sounds very great, I will check it as soon as i can!

Answer (score 2):

The max value for a SQL Server DateTime value is 9999-12-31 23:59:59.997 - note that it ends in a 7!

This code works fine;

```
declare @MaxDateTime datetime; set @MaxDateTime = '9999-12-31 23:59:59.997'
```

This code does not;

```
declare @MaxDateTime datetime; set @MaxDateTime = '9999-12-31 23:59:59.999'
```

If you are wondering why the max value ends in a 7 it's because of the way that SQL Server stores DateTime values internally.

Hope this helps,

Rhys